# how to install staza for python 3.7 (this command is returning error (!pip install stanza ))

Tags: python-3.7, lemmatization, stanza

I am trying to instal stanza for lemmatization purposes using this command: !pip install stanza but it's returning the following error. Please help I am new to python.

Collecting stanza
Using cached stanza-1.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch>=1.3.0 (from stanza) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch>=1.3.0 (from stanza)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. I went to https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ and installed the torch, then it was solved.